# how to use beautifulSoup to extract html5 elements such as <section>

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I intend to extract the article text from an NYT article. However I don't know how to extract by html5 tags such as section name.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.nytimes.com/2019/10/24/opinion/chuck-schumer-electric-car.html?action=click&module=Opinion&pgtype=Homepage')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
data = soup.findAll(text=True)
```

The main text is wrapped in a section named 'articleBody'. What kind of soup.find() syntax can I use to extract that?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The find method searches tags, it doesn't differentiate HTML5 from any other (X)HTML tag name

```
article = soup.find("section",{"name":"articleBody"})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is only returning a large js file. is it because of pay wall? how else can I extract plain text?

Comment: Probably the paywall, or NYT loads dynamic content using JS from a backing API. In that case, you'd have to start using selenium WebDriver

Answer (score 1):

You can scrape the pre-loaded data from script tag and parse with json library. The first code block brings back a little more content than you wanted.

You can further restrict by looking up ids of paragraphs within body, and use those to filter content, **as shown in bottom block**; You then get exactly the article content you describe.

```
import requests, re, json

r = requests.get('https://www.nytimes.com/2019/10/24/opinion/chuck-schumer-electric-car.html?action=click&module=Opinion&pgtype=Homepage')
p = re.compile(r'window\.__preloadedData = (.*})')
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])

for k,v in data['initialState'].items():
    if k.startswith('$Article') and 'formats' in v:
        print(v['text@stripHtml'] if 'text@stripHtml' in v else v['text'])
```

You can explore the json here: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=f9ae1fb774af439d8e9b32247db9d853

---

The following shows how to use additional logic to limit to just output you want:

```
ids = []

for k,v in data['initialState'].items():
    if k.startswith('$Article') and v['__typename'] == 'ParagraphBlock' and 'content' in v:
        ids += [v['content'][0]['id']]

for k,v in data['initialState'].items():
    if k in ids:
        print(v['text'])
```